# SqlConnection Get list of all tables with type

Tags: c#, database-schema, sqlconnection

In my C# code, I create a SqlConnection instance and call the GetSchema method of it as `con.GetSchema("Tables");`. I need the list of all user tables, system tables, system views, user views separately if possible (with different methods/parameters) or in a single list (provided with a way to filter from it saying using Type info)

Got an answer here [Getting system tables and views thru SqlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487016/getting-system-tables-and-views-thru-sqlconnection), but it is so confusing and I am not sure why both select is exactly same in that SQL.

Comment: Meaning, I have to then apply filter when I need only view for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

`"SELECT * FROM sys.objects ORDER BY type_desc"` you can then filter using the `column type_desc`.

For all columns in all the tables with type use :

`"SELECT * FROM dbName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS ORDER BY table_name"`

These work for MSSQL.

Comment: The 1st Sql does not get me any system views. The 2nd one does return columns of only user tables and not system tables/views :(